# Print a graph of numbers in a horizontal and vertical graph using an array in java

Tags: java, arrays

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Assignment5 {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int a;

    System.out.println("Please enter a number between 1 and 9:");
    int[] graph = new int[10];
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i){
      a = scan.nextInt();
      graph[i] = a;
    }
  }

  // this is the method I'm required to use for 
  // this array assignment

  public static void printVertical(int[] graph){
    for(int i = 0; i < graph.length; i++){
      for(int j = 0; j < graph[i]; j++){
        System.out.print(" " + graph[i]);
      }
      System.out.println();
    }
  }

  // this is what I've got for the horizontal method

  // I took the for loop and nested for loop from the vertical.
  // I'm stuck on changing the variable to flip the graph -90 degrees

  public static void printHorizontal(int[] graph){
    for(int i = 0; i < graph.length; i++){
      for(int h = 0; h < graph[i]; h++){
        System.out.print(" " + graph[i]);
      }
      System.out.println();
    }
  }

  public static int calculateTotal(int[] graph){
    int sum = 0;
    for( int num : graph ){
      sum = sum + num;
    }
    System.out.print("The total is: " + sum);
    return sum;
  }
}
```

My for loop in the `printVertical` method isn't returning the graph properly.

What am I doing wrong?

The output needs to look like this:

```
    Sample output:
    2 4 6 8 9 8 6 4 3 2
    ---- Vertical Graph ----
    2 2
    4 4 4 4
    6 6 6 6 6 6
    8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8
    9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9
    8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8
    6 6 6 6 6 6
    4 4 4 4
    3 3 3
    2 2

    ---- Horizontal Graph ----

            9
          8 9 8
          8 9 8
        6 8 9 8 6
        6 8 9 8 6
      4 6 8 9 8 6 4 
      4 6 8 9 8 6 4
    2 4 6 8 9 8 6 4 2

    The total is: 52
    2 4 6 8 9 8 6 4 2
```

Comment: What does your output look like?

Answer (score 1):

Consider the code given below.It might solve your problem..

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Assignment5 {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    int a;
    System.out.println("Please enter a number between 1 and 9:");
    int[] graph = new int[10];
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i){
        a = scan.nextInt();
        graph[i] = a;
    }
    System.out.println("----------Vertical Graph-------------");
    printVerticalGraph(graph);
    System.out.println("----------Horizontal Graph-------------");
    printHorizontalGraph(graph);
}
    public static void printVerticalGraph(int[] graph)
    {
        for (int i = 0 ; i < graph.length; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0 ; j < graph[i] ; j++)
            {
                System.out.print(graph[i]+" ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
    public static void printHorizontalGraph(int[] graph)
    {
        for (int i = 0 ; i < graph.length; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0 ; j < graph.length; j++ )
            {
                if (i > 10 - graph[j])
                {
                    System.out.print(graph[j]);
                }
                else
                    System.out.print( " ");
                System.out.print(" ");
            }
            System.out.print("\n");
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the sample output..

```
Please enter a number between 1 and 9:
2
4
6
8
9
8
6
4
3
2
----------Vertical Graph-------------
2 2
4 4 4 4
6 6 6 6 6 6
8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8
9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9
8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8
6 6 6 6 6 6
4 4 4 4
3 3 3
2 2
----------Horizontal Graph-------------


        9
      8 9 8
      8 9 8
    6 8 9 8 6
    6 8 9 8 6
  4 6 8 9 8 6 4
  4 6 8 9 8 6 4 3
2 4 6 8 9 8 6 4 3 2
```

Comment: this is perfect guys thank you! Could I ask for help in the printHorizontal method. I know there needs to be a variable change but it doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: @user2133510: how you want your Horizontal graph to look like?

Comment: Sorry about that I didn't originally add my entire code, but I edited it just a second ago.

Comment: @user2133510 you are most welcome. If this solved your problem marked the answer as accepted . see here how to accept an answer http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 0):

```
package Kashish;

public class arrayseries1 {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    int arr[]={2,5,4,1,6,9};

    System.out.println("--Horizontal--");

    for (int i=0;i<arr.length;i++)
    {
        int j=arr[i];
        for(int k=0;k<j;k++)
        {
            System.out.print(j);
        }
        System.out.print("\n");
    }
    System.out.println("--Vertical--");
    int max=0;                       /// take the max element
    for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++)    ///to find max
    {
        if(arr[i]>max)
        {
            max=arr[i];
        }
    }
    int x=max;

    for(int i=0;i<x;i++)
    {
        //int j=arr[i];
        for(int j=0;j<arr.length;j++)
        {
            int k=max-arr[j];
            if(k>0)
                System.out.print(" ");   
            else 
                System.out.print(arr[j]);
            System.out.print(" ");
        }System.out.print("\n");
        max--;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to this answer.